# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I hope someone answer the below error code, I am working on supervised ML and I got an error.

My library details (As I downgraded both the above package to current package details mentioned above many developer have said to downgrade the version it will work, but in my case it's not working):

- Numpy : 1.18.5 Current version (earlier it was 1.20.3)
- TensorFlow : 2.5.0 Current version (earlier it was 2.4.1)
- Python : 3.8.8
- Keras : 2.4.3

Here is the code:

```
# Defining the LSTM model to be fit
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(85, input_shape=(1, 53)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# Fitting the model
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=70, batch_size=175, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# Plotting the training progression
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

And the error:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-251aaaf9021e> in <module>
      1 # Defining the LSTM model to be fit
      2 model = Sequential()
----> 3 model.add(LSTM(85, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
      4 model.add(Dense(1))
      5 model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

 NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_2/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. 
   This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Comment: Your code differs from error you have attached. The code has line `model.add(LSTM(85, input_shape=(1, 53)))`, but the error says this is ` model.add(LSTM(85, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))`.

Comment: do you know how to resolve

Comment: @Kaveh input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])  , where train_X.shape[1] =1 and train_X.shape[2]=53

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: @molbdnilo  my problem is related with LSTM

Comment: Perhaps, but the [ML](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) family of programming languages has nothing to do with your question, since Python is not one of them.

Comment: Can you try in this combination `tensorflow-2.5`, `numpy-1.19.5` with `python-3.9` and let us know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got out the solution while adding LSTM model which depends on layer input_shape was not appropriate, so change the shape to

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(85, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

# Fitting the model
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=70, batch_size=175, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# Plotting the training progression
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain the answer a bit.

Comment: @stuckoverflow You can check https://github.com/MohammadFneish7/Keras_LSTM_Diagram to learn more about how to properly shape LSTM input.